# Best model for Android Master / Detail UI where Master is tabbed

Tags: android, android-fragments, master-detail, android-tablayout, android-tabbed-activity

I'm an iOS developer and new to Android development. I recently completed one iOS to Android port that was simple enough but I'm now unsure of how to proceed with the next much more complex app port.

What I'm unsure of is how to best replicate a universal App which makes use of Master/Detail split screen on tablet. The complication is that the Master is tabbed and I can find no reference apps or examples to give me the confidence that any approach is the best long term solution.

The previous, simple, app I ported just used a chain of Activities branching off from a main activity.

Each tabbed master is not a single screen but potentially as deep as several views which can collapse back to the original. I'm not sure if fragments is the correct approach and I believe fragments only recently became nest-able.

I'm including an example screen shot of an example iOS App to illustrate better what I'm trying to achieve on Android. The iOS app is landscape only so rotation of the android app to portrait isn't important.

Thanks in advance.

[image: iOS Master/Detail split view with Tabbed Master]

Comment: As per me 1 Activity with 2 Fragments is best suited for above app screen sample you have shared. For more information on fragments refer -https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html .

Comment: So for each of the 3 sections and all their sub menus I'd need to create an Activity with 2 Fragments? I'm a little confused about the navigation. There's the stock templates in Studio for tabbed and for Master/Detail but neither alludes to how to combine them or deal with sub menus.